# 1.16 - When an invisible mob wears armor, does that increase its detection distance?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

According to the Minecraft Wiki,

> Mobs do not attack or sense [invisible players] until the player is a lot closer than normal.

> A player with no armor can be detected at 7% of the usual detection distance.

> Any single piece of armor increases this to 17.5% of the usual distance, and each additional piece increases this by another 17.5%.

I am wondering if this also applies to non-player entities, such as a villager.

Comment: Not sure this applies to villagers since they cant wear armor. Do you mean how well a villager could detect a mob with armor and invisiblity?

Comment: Villagers can wear armor